# 403 forbidden. WebException was unhandled .NET

Tags: c#, distance, webrequest, http-status-code-403

I have coded a class to calculate the distance between two coordinates. But as soon as I run the project, it gives an error:

> WebException was unhandled.
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

My code is:

```
public Tuple<double, double> GetCoords(string Streetnumber, string Streetname, string Cityname, string Country)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    string clientId = "///"; =
    string key = "//";
    string address = Streetnumber + "+" + Streetname + ",+" + Cityname + ",+" + Country;

    var urlRequest = "/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + address + "&client=" + clientId;
    System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1 myhmacsha1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1();
    myhmacsha1.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
    var hash = myhmacsha1.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(urlRequest));
    string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hash).Replace("+", "-").Replace("/", "_");
    WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

    doc.Load("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + address + "&client=" + clientId + "&signature=" + signature);

    string longitude = doc.SelectSingleNode("//GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng").InnerText;
    double lng = LongitudePlace(longitude);
    string latitude = doc.SelectSingleNode("//GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat").InnerText;
    double lat = LatitudePlace(latitude);
    return Tuple.Create(lng, lat);
}
```

I also have some other methods but they are irrelevant to this problem. The error is given at:

```
doc.Load("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + address + "&client=" + clientId + "&signature=" + signature);
```

Maybe this is easy to fix, but I tried a lot of things. My `clientID` is correct, also the key which is the secret key at console.developer.google.com if I'm not mistaking.

I tried a test address of "1600", "Amphitheatre+Parkway", "Mountain+View", "CA".

How to solve the error?

Comment: might be your string building. suggest you use url encode or similar https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Have you taken the generated string and pasted it into a browser?

Comment: @RonBeyer yes I did, and it didnt work.

Comment: Then something is wrong with the way you are generating the string, and it doesn't have anything to do with the code. I'd look up API examples and find out where your request string is wrong. Since you are getting 403, I'd start with the secret key or your client ID.

Comment: Have you checked the API specs to make sure you're passing the correct parameters? When I tested the URL with only the address it worked correctly ([Try it](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA))

Comment: @RonBeyer I pasted my url and crypto key at https://m4b-url-signer.appspot.com/ and it gave one warning: Client parameter is required.

Comment: I checked my ClientID at google.developer.com and it is exactly the same.

Comment: @amura.cxg can you paste what you've used in doc.Load(string url/filename)?

Comment: I didn't test the actual app, I just tested it in my browser, which I realize was useless.
Reading Google's [page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth) about the signature, when they create the signature they use the full URL (including the https://...) try changing `urlRequest` to `urlRequest = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + address + "&client=" + clientId`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your signature may not be formed correctly. Specifically, it's missing part of the URL. Below is an edited version of your code using code provided by Google to sign the URL. The code can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth#signature_examples)

**Code**

```
public Tuple<double, double> GetCoords(string streetNumber, string streetName, string cityName, string country)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    string clientId = "gme-" + "///";
    string key = "//"; //Note this is NOT your API key, it's the Client Secret
    string address = streetNumber + "+" + streetName + ",+" + cityName + ",+" + country;

    WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

    doc.Load(Sign("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + address + "&client=" + clientId, key));

    string longitude = doc.SelectSingleNode("//GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng").InnerText;
    double lng = LongitudePlace(longitude);
    string latitude = doc.SelectSingleNode("//GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat").InnerText;
    double lat = LatitudePlace(latitude);
    return Tuple.Create(lng, lat);
}

//From the Google
public static string Sign(string url, string keyString) 
{
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

    // converting key to bytes will throw an exception, need to replace '-' and '_' characters first.
    string usablePrivateKey = keyString.Replace("-", "+").Replace("_", "/");
    byte[] privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(usablePrivateKey);

    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    byte[] encodedPathAndQueryBytes = encoding.GetBytes(uri.LocalPath + uri.Query);

    // compute the hash
    HMACSHA1 algorithm = new HMACSHA1(privateKeyBytes);
    byte[] hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(encodedPathAndQueryBytes);

    // convert the bytes to string and make url-safe by replacing '+' and '/' characters
    string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hash).Replace("+", "-").Replace("/", "_");

    // Add the signature to the existing URI.
    return uri.Scheme+"://"+uri.Host+uri.LocalPath + uri.Query +"&signature=" + signature;
}
```

Comment: Still not working, giving the same error at doc.Load(Sign("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + address + "&client=" + clientId, key));

Comment: Are you putting `gme-` before your client ID?

Comment: @amura.csg  no, my clientid starts with numbers, continues with letters and ends with .apps.googleusercontent.com

Comment: When I was testing some code I was using [this](https://m4b-url-signer.appspot.com/) to see if my signature was correct. One thing I noticed was if I left `gme-` from my Client ID it would indicate my client option was missing. Your URL should be something like `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=<address>&client=gme-numbers-stuff.apps.googleusercontent.com`

Comment: still not working.. this is very weird. First time something like this appears and not working properly after trying to fix it.

Comment: Yeah that's very strange. Might need to talk to Google support and see what's up. Wish I could have been of more help

Comment: ,cxg thank you very much for your help. Appreciate it. Exactly, maybe Google support could do something about it.